# Defined Offset and Limit in Get Method for Podio API in getting app records

Tags: api, podio, klipfolio

I'm trying to get all records from Podio and create as datasource in KLIPFOLIO.

I'm using this API URL - `https://api.podio.com/item/app/{App_ID}`

If I just defined this way (`https://api.podio.com/item/app/{App_ID}`) no param for offset or limit, I'm getting a result.

However, If I do like this `https://api.podio.com/item/app/{App_ID}?limit=500&offset=500` I'm getting an error `"Unable to retrieve data. Try a different URL or check to make sure the resource is available."`

This is documented on https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215546958-Creating-a-Podio-Data-Source but it is not working.

Please help how to define offset and limit using URL parameters for get method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cURL to ensure that all params are working well?

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth2 <auth_token>" -X GET "https://api.podio.com/item/app/<app_id>?offset=10&limit=10"
```